# How to subscribe to click event of html form?

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-4.0, google-checkout

I have a google checkout "buy now" button and I want to add dynamically created information to send when it's clicked. How do I do that?

The button's html is:

```
<form action="https://sandbox.google.com/checkout/..." id="Form1" method="post" name="..." target="_top">
<input name="item_name_1" type="hidden" value="..." />
...
<input alt="" src="https://sandbox.google.com/checkout/buttons/buy.gif?merchant_id=..." type="image" />
</form>
```

So what do I add? (And if possible, I'd like to do that through ASP.Net code.)

I tried adding `onclick="Button1_Click"` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is for Google Checkout, you should consider using the existing [.Net library for Google Checkout](https://developers.google.com/checkout/samplecode).

While the above suggestion will work, the correct (secure) way of doing so is [documented here](https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_HTML_API#create_checkout_cart). The XML alternative (signing) is [here](https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API#create_checkout_cart), one of which allows you to do a direct FORM POST to Google in a secure manner.

Submission via client methods will always make you susceptible to tampering - it would make little difference (security-wise) than just doing a basic HTML form post to Google.

---

**Updated**:

> ...*doesn't support buy now*...

At the end of the day, there are 2 things that make "BUY NOW" different from any other "cart" submission:

1. the image
2. single item purchase for Buy Now (vs. one or more for other implementations).

See this [sample code from the .Net Library](http://code.google.com/p/google-checkout-dotnet-sample-code/source/browse/examples/post_cart/simple.aspx). It should give you all you need....

---

**Update 2**:

There isn't anything "rigid" about the library. You don't have to use everything in it - you can even just take advantage of all the plumbing already created for you.

### Simple Example, implementing BUY NOW, using Google Checkout .Net Library

Web Forms Code (aspx):

```
<p>Some ASP.net button:<br />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="BUY ME NOW" onclick="Button1_Click" /><br />

An ASP.NET Image Button using BUY NOW Image:<br />
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="https://checkout.google.com/buttons/buy.gif?merchant_id=[USE YOUR OWN MERCHANT ID]&amp;w=117&amp;h=48&amp;style=white&amp;variant=text&amp;loc=en_US" onclick="ImageButton1_Click" />
```

At this point this is what you see in your browser:

[image: screen shot Google Checkout Buy Now]

Code (inline or code-behind):

```
using GCheckout.Checkout;
using GCheckout.Util;

....

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    doSomething();
}

protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    doSomething();
}

private void doSomething()
{
    /**
     * Use the correct Merchant ID and Key based on GCheckout.EnvironmentType
     * You cannot mix/match sandbox and production id or key
     */
    CheckoutShoppingCartRequest Req = new CheckoutShoppingCartRequest("your_production_MID", "your_production_KEY", GCheckout.EnvironmentType.Production, "USD", 20);

    /**
     * Everything from this point is a copy and paste
     * from .net libary sample code
     * http://code.google.com/p/google-checkout-dotnet-sample-code/source/browse/examples/post_cart/simple.aspx
     */
    Req.AddItem("Mars bar", "Packed with peanuts", 0.75m, 2);

    //lets make sure we can add 2 different flat rate shipping amounts
    Req.AddFlatRateShippingMethod("UPS Ground", 5);

    //Add a rule to tax all items at 7.5% for Ohio
    Req.AddStateTaxRule("OH", 7.5, true);

    GCheckoutResponse Resp = Req.Send();
    if (Resp.IsGood)
    {
        Response.Redirect(Resp.RedirectUrl, true);
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("Resp.ResponseXml = " + Resp.ResponseXml + "<br>");
        Response.Write("Resp.RedirectUrl = " + Resp.RedirectUrl + "<br>");
        Response.Write("Resp.IsGood = " + Resp.IsGood + "<br>");
        Response.Write("Resp.ErrorMessage = " + Resp.ErrorMessage + "<br>");
    }
}
```

### Important

The above is just **sample code** to illustrate what you can do with the .Net Library. **To comply with Google Checkout implementation policy, use the ImageButton implementation** - it ensures that you are using Google's BUY NOW button (unaltered, etc.).

Comment: Their API doesn't seem to support the "Buy Now" button.

Comment: I tried using the .net library, but when I got to changing the button's image - setting the button's `ImageUrl` property just made it disappear. Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: Thank you very much for your perseverance. I've decided to use their .net library as you suggested. (Now stuck at Google not processing my NotificationAcknowledgment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177384/google-checkout-notification-acknowledgment-failing .)

Answer (score 1):

ASP is a server-side script, so you can't launch it after the page is loaded. The onlcick attribute is used to launch javascript.
Two workaround's:

- What you can do is redirect it to another page, which redirects to google checkout.
- Using javascript and ajax, load the dynamic information, and submit it using javascript

Comment: Thanks. I don't have experience with scripts, but I might be able to manage the redirect. (Though I still don't know how I would then add the information in the code there :)

Comment: "you can't launch it after the page is loaded" – I don't know if it's called "launch", but things _can_ happen then – for example – a clicking of an ASP.net button calls the appropriate event handler in the codebehind.

Comment: woops, my fault, read over the .net part. Never mind my answer then