# Google checkout notification acknowledgment failing

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-checkout

I have a callback url that gets called, and I can process it. However - Google doesn't process my acknowledgment. This is all in `EnvironmentType.Sandbox`.

In the Google checkout "Integration Console" I get the following message:

> We encountered an error processing your notification acknowledgment.
>   The error we got is: Error parsing notification acknowledgment.

And the details are:
What they sent me: `serial-number=...`.

What they received:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<notification-acknowledgment xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" serial-number="here is the same serial number they sent me" xmlns="http://checkout.google.com/schema/2" />

<!DOCTYPE html...
```

The code I'm using:

```
GCheckout.AutoGen.NotificationAcknowledgment response = new GCheckout.AutoGen.NotificationAcknowledgment();
response.serialnumber = serialNumber;
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(GCheckout.Util.EncodeHelper.Serialize(response));
HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 200;
```

What's the mistake here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this "code behind" code from the [.Net Library examples](http://code.google.com/p/google-checkout-dotnet-sample-code/source/browse/examples/api25notification/Default.aspx.cs)

If you are using an aspx file, remove all the HTML content in it as shown in `aspx` [source of the same example](http://code.google.com/p/google-checkout-dotnet-sample-code/source/browse/examples/api25notification/Default.aspx)

`Response.End()` will also work because it stops any further Reponse content from being returned (effectively does the same thing - prevents the HTML content in the Web Forms (`aspx` file) from being sent).

You can also consider using a generic handler (`ashx`) instead of an aspx page for your callback url.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this question is solved by an answer to another question of mine: [How can I create an http response from scratch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11180847/how-can-i-create-an-http-response-from-scratch) .

The solution is to add:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```