# How can I create an http response from scratch?

Tags: asp.net, html, httpresponse, google-checkout

I have code that returns an http response, but it also includes the content of the page. How can I create a response from scratch so it won't include anything except what I put in it?

My code now:

```
GCheckout.AutoGen.NotificationAcknowledgment response = new GCheckout.AutoGen.NotificationAcknowledgment();
response.serialnumber = serialNumber;
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(GCheckout.Util.EncodeHelper.Serialize(response));
HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 200;
```

Comment: Is this WebForms? If so, is it in an .aspx page?

Comment: I hope this answers your question http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.aspx

Comment: @MichaelLiu aspx. There's no form there. it's in a callback url.

Comment: But right now the HTTP response includes the content of the .aspx too?

Comment: @MichaelLiu Well actually now that I checked again - it includes the content of the page's _master page_. (What I'm trying to solve is - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177384/google-checkout-notification-acknowledgment-failing - perhaps it's failing because of extra stuff in the response.)

Comment: @HatSoft Unfortunately, I don't know enough to implement all of this myself, and the google code I'm trying to learn from - uses `HttpContext`. But thanks for the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you've set the status code and written out the response content, call [`HttpContext.Current.Response.End()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.end.aspx) to stop the execution of the current request.